# Failed to update react-native to 0.59.2 with android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I created a project since react-native 0.55.4, and now I plan to upgrade to latest version (0.59.2).
With `iOS` I have updated successfully. Unfortunately, Android I have failed with upgrading. It seems like many changes are requried for `Android`. The `gradle` sync successfully, and build successfully, but when I type `react-native run-android`. and when the application has installed to mobile or emulator, it displays "Could not connect to development server."

Here something I changed:
gradle-wrapper.properties
- distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

build.gradle
- dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' }
- the build tools version is 28.0.3

app/build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
  pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
}

splits {
  abi {
    reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
  }
}
```

I also update the metro.config.js and babel.config.js follow rn 0.59.2

Old Environment
 "react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.4",
New Environment
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.2",

I thought that I have missed something with android. Please correct me.

**updated answer.**

go to AndroidManifest.xml then add

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

inside application tag. everything is work. 
What is the *usesCleartextTraffic* mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means **accept http request**(usually not encrypted text).
After Android 9.0(API 28), the **HTTP** request is forbidden by default.It is requested to use **HTTPS** for the security reason.So if you want to use http connection by default, you can set this property to 'true'.

RN send http request to the dev-server, so you can set this property to 'true' to avoid check.

And set target SDK under 28 or add config file to include domain can also do this as well.